# echo <script> got me crazy

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-php-sdk

using [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login) on IIS;

```
<?php 
    $key = '**********';
    $value = '**********';
    session_start ( );

    $code = $_REQUEST [ 'code' ];
    if ( empty ( $code ) )
    {
        $_SESSION [ 'state' ] = md5 ( uniqid ( rand ( ) , true ) );
        $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . $key . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode ( $value ) . '&state=' . $_SESSION [ 'state' ];
        echo('<script> top.location.href=' . $dialog_url . ';</script>');
    }
?>
```

**Result:**

```
top.location.href=' . $dialog_url . ';'); } ?>
```

Please try your suggestion before posting it as I have tried more than 40 suggestions, reviewed all similar questions and searched it for last 2 hours.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a variable first, then echo the variable?

Comment: The answers are correct. So your code is broken somewhere else

Comment: @chumkiu This's my whole code file :( There's no somewhere else !

Comment: Are you sure that your server is configured for php files? Which extension have your file?

Comment: @chumkiu my file is HTML one, my server is local IIS

Comment: @chumkiu Then the whole file would be outputted, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm sure! If you view the html source of your page, you see exactly all php code. See my answer

Comment: See this http://ardeearam.com/blog/2010/04/21/how-to-execute-php-from-html-file-in-iis/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server do not parse your file as php. That's the symptom.

See [how to configure your IIS server](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) for parse html file as PHP.

EDIT for completeness:

As mentioned by other answers you should add double quotes around `$dialog_url` for prevent javascript error

```
echo('<script> top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
```

Comment: Then the whole file would be outputted, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MiniGod Yes but if you see that in browser, you see only the output that he says. But if you see the source you see all the php code. Try to copy and paste the code and disable php on your server and see the browser output :)

Comment: You still need to wrap the $dialog_url in quotes as that's a JS string. And you're programming PHP but don't have the server setup properly to interpret the very f'ing scripting language you're using. Oh.My.GOD!

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments, this is in an `.html` file.  Rename the file to have the `.php` extension and make sure you view it through a server such as Apache.  If you don't have one handy, I'd recommend [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

(old answer, still relevant)
You need to use double quotes in the script:

```
echo '<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>';
```

See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/WBX5mrWE), with most of the rest [here](http://codepad.org/wsM7uAiT)

Comment: **Result:** `top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";'; } ?>`

Comment: It's working in my codepad example.  Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo '<script> top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>';
```

Comment: **Result:** `top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";'; } ?>`

Comment: It can't be, check everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo("<script>top.location.href='{$dialog_url}';</script>");
```

Wrapped $dialog_url in quotes and the whole thing in double quotes to make it easy.

Comment: **Result:** `top.location.href='{$dialog_url}';"); } ?>`